# Android: Destroy application activity stack when android clear it from memory

Tags: java, android, performance

We have application that contains multiples activities.

Common business-logic always run in MainActivity. And from MainActivity we navigate to other Activities (Activity1, Activity2, ...) with specific data.

It's works very well.

But if we minimize the application and then move to others applications, wait any time (near 5 mins). And then open(maximize) application again our activities show empty data.

(Android kill our activities!)

Yes, we known about SaveInstanceState that created for this purposes. But in our application it's not best solution, because we have many operations that contained in MainActivity. And if android kill our activities, we want reopen application from MainActivity, but not from Activity1, Activity2, ...

Our MainActivity code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.w("MainActivity", "Activities already created, we after activity kill process");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

It's works, but can we do it with other right way?

Comment: Why does your mainActivity intent is to restart the mainActivity activity? It doesn't do anything if you've navigated to another activity.

Comment: @XepterX Thanks, you are right, we can finish other activities without navigating to MainActivity.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't fight the framework.**

Save and restore your instance state.  Do not depend on `MainActivity` actively working (or even existing at all) when it's in the backstack.  Move those background operations to a `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

The "right way" would be to change your whole app architecture. An issue with your approach is that  configuration changes would trigger this flow, and redirect the user to the `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You can set  `android:noHistory="true"`, for each of the smaller Activites. That way, when you return to your app after minimizing, it will always start from the `MainActivity`.

EDIT: In general though, you should not be fighting the android framework and instead structure your app according to it.

Comment: Thanks. If we set NoHistory flag it's also breaks BackPress navigation, it's not solution for this case.